# Go Library automation

Tags: go

To learn go I am trying to build an open source library, I like the language but since I am still a bit new I can't find good direction on how to automate building, testing and releasing.
I had the idea to use Makefiles etc.. am I in the right direction or there is better tools to do that.

Best,
Khaled

Comment: Start by reading [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Comment: I did read all of that, my question is about workflow more than the language

Comment: The document shows the commands to use to build, test and fetch Go packages.  It does leave pushing a package to a repo as an exercise for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some useful links

- Here you have a link for best practice for coding

https://peter.bourgon.org/go-best-practices-2016/

https://golang.org/doc/code.html

- Working with packages, useful links.

http://thenewstack.io/understanding-golang-packages/

https://www.goinggo.net/2013/07/how-packages-work-in-go-language.html

- I recommend to review the open source libraries to get an idea.(there are tons of them)

https://github.com/urfave/cli

https://github.com/boltdb/raw

https://github.com/matryer/try

- To automate your project. I recommend to see projects like Drone

https://github.com/drone/drone

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/tockins/realize too

Comment: @AJPennster Thanks for share. It looks interesting. I'll check it.